# Artificial Intelligence

Tags: java, lisp, artificial-intelligence

I have come across AI modules in JAVA.Is JAVA suitable for AI development?Is it comparable to LISP in terms of functionality and flexibility?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. All high level languages are suitable for AI. It depends on what do you intend.

Take a look at this question and the answers:

[What is a good programming language for AI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82036/what-is-a-good-programming-language-for-ai)

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer you can mark the tick beside it. It's a good practice to close the question